# Is There A Way To Stop Lag?

Tags: 12.10

I’m playing games and there is always lag,I was wonder if there is a way to remove and possibly prevent lag without downloading anything or using the terminal?

I tried looking but there is only stuff on removing lag on Windows :(

Comment: Let me pull out my crystal ball.

Answer (score 1):

Lag can be caused by many different factors, and it depends on the software you are attempting to run. The key causes are usually, INTERNET CONNECTION, cpu, storage device, graphics card, and ram.

If you have a poor graphics card try running the game a really low resoulution with eye candy dialed down.

If you have a poor cpu don't run anything else at the same time as you are playing (eg don't listen to you music collection at the same time).

If you have a slow storage device (for example a laptop hard drive) consider setting up a ramdrive (eg tempfs) and running the game from their via a chroot.

If you have not much ram consider adding a larger swap partition and store it on the fastest drive you have.

If you have a terrible internet connection, try adjusting the game's internet settings to match what you have. Remember most internet connections have bad times of day and good times of day due to high or low usage of other users, so try playing at a different time and see if that helps.

Comment: This is actually a quite good answer to a bad question...